# Count rows for each ID that fall between two dates, when using two tables

Tags: r, count, powerbi, rowcount

For each ID in one table (Table 1), how can I count the number of rows in another table (Table 2) which fall between a start date and end date (two columns in the first table) in R?

**Table 1:**

| contact_number | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2024 |
| 1234 | 01/01/2022 | 01/01/2023 |

**Table 2:**

| contact_number | visit_type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 02/01/2023 |
| 123 | 2 | 05/01/2023 |
| 1234 | 2 | 05/01/2022 |

**Output wanted:**

| contact_number | start_date | end_date | visits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01/01/2023 | 01/01/2024 | 2 |
| 1234 | 01/01/2022 | 01/01/2023 | 1 |

I am wanting to replicate a Power BI DAX query:

```
visits_per_membership = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table 2'),
    FILTER(
        'Table 2',
        'Table 2'[contact_number] = Table 1[contact_number] && 'Table 2'[EntryDate].[Date] >= Table 1[start_date].[Date] && 'Table 2'[EntryDate].[Date] < Table 1[renewal_date].[Date])
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution, mapping over rows of `table1` and comparing to `table2` by id and dates:

```
table1$visits <- mapply(
  \(contact, start, end) sum(
    table2$contact_number == contact & 
    table2$date >= start &
    table2$date <= end
  ),
  table1$contact_number,
  table1$start_date,
  table1$end_date
  )

table1
```

```
  contact_number start_date   end_date visits
1            123 2023-01-01 2024-01-01      2
2           1234 2022-01-01 2023-01-01      1
```

Or using `dplyr::left_join()`:

```
library(dplyr) # >= v1.1.0:

table1 %>%
  left_join(table2, multiple = "all") %>%
  summarize(
    visits = sum(between(date, start_date, end_date)),
    .by = c(contact_number, start_date, end_date)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.table` approach

```
dt1[, visits := dt2[dt1, on = .(date >= start_date, date <= end_date)][, .N, by = contact_number]$N]

   contact_number start_date   end_date visits
1:            123 2023-01-01 2024-01-01      2
2:           1234 2022-01-01 2023-01-01      1
```

**sample data used**

```
dt1 <- fread("contact_number    start_date  end_date
123     01/01/2023  01/01/2024
1234    01/01/2022  01/01/2023")

dt2 <- fread("contact_number    visit_type  date
123     1   02/01/2023
123     2   05/01/2023
1234    2   05/01/2022")

dt1[, c("start_date", "end_date") := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y"), 
    .SDcols = c("start_date", "end_date")]
dt2[, date := as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have attempted to use you solution but unfortunately I receiving the error: Error in `:=`(visits, True_G[ML_data1, on = .(posted >= start_date, posted <=  : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: I guess your data is not in `data.table` format then? use `data.table::setDT()`. If you are not familiar with the `data.table`-package, i suggest reading the vignettes.

Comment: Hi thanks for that, yes I forgot to put the tables in data.table format. I am still receiving the error: Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation.